# Python script that surrounds each line in file with apostrophe

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python script that takes an input file, manipulate it's content and writes the result to an output file.

I want to surround every line with quotes.
Currently I created the script below.

```
import sys
import re

inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]

with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()


def manipulate_data(lines):
    content = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in lines]

    res = [re.sub(r"(.+)", r"'\g<0>',", y) for y in content]
    return res


processedLines = manipulate_data(lines)

with open(outFile,'w') as o:
    for line in processedLines:
        o.write(line)
```

I run it with `python3 script.py input.txt output.txt`

It runs, but I wish to change this so that it writes to the output file line by line. I also feel like I am unnecessarily using `[do_something for something in somethings]` twice.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do string formatting while reading the file and write the updated string to the outfile!

```
with open(inFile,'r') as f, open(outFile,'w') as w:
    for line in f.readlines():
        w.write("'%s'\n" % line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read lines from one file, modify and write to another file, all in one go:

```
with open(inFile, 'r') as inf, open(outFile, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write('"{}"\n'.format(line.strip('\n')))
```

Comment: this will put the end quote AFTER the line break, which i'm not sure is desired. Maybe something like `print >>outf, '"'+line.strip('\n')+'"'` ?

Comment: @Triggernometry, Nice catch! Thank you.